# Filtro de palavras-chave com outros campos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema aonde preciso realizar uma filtragem de usuários, e nessa filtragem serão utilizados diversos campos simultâneos (nome, cpf, sexo, idade e etc.), o problema começa quando eu tento acrescentar um campo com palavras-chave, pois preciso pesquisar em no mínimo 3 tabelas distintas as palavras inseridas, juntamente aos campos citados anteriormente. Sem usar as palavras-chave, a filtragem funciona normalmente.

Estou utilizando o framework do CodeIgniter na versão 3.1.10, e nas models, estou utilizando o query builder.

Já tentei criar um array com a string separada por vírgulas vindo do form, utilizando o like ($this->db->like($array);), mas não funcionou, tentei também o group ($this->db->group_start();) e não funcionou, que inclusive utilizo em outra filtragem (sem palavras-chave) e funciona corretamente.

Tentei fazer dessa maneira, mas sem sucesso:

```
public function filter_candidatos($nome, $sobrenome, $cpf, $palavraChave, $funcoes, $idadeIni, $idadeFin, $sexo, $pcd, $cid, $escolaridade, $pais, $estado, $cidades, $conceito, $status){
    // FILTRO ADICIONANDO LOCALIZAÇÃO
    if(!empty($pais) || !empty($estado) || !empty($cidades)){
        $this->db->join("endereco as e", "e.id_endereco = u.id_endereco");
        (!empty($pais) ? $this->db->where("e.id_pais", $pais) : "");
        $this->db->where("e.id_estado", $estado);
        if(!empty($cidades)){
            $cidade = explode(",",$cidades);
            $this->db->where_in("e.cidade", $cidade);
        }
    }
    // FILTRO ADICIONANDO FUNÇÕES
    if(!empty($funcoes)){
        $funcao = explode(",",$funcoes);
        $this->db->join("funcao_usuario as fu", "fu.id_usuario = u.id_usuario");
        $this->db->where_in("fu.id_funcao", $funcao);
    }
    // FILTRO ADICIONANDO ESCOLARIDADE
    if(!empty($escolaridade)){
        $escolaridade = explode(",", $escolaridade);
        $this->db->where_in("u.escolaridade", $escolaridade);
    }
    // FILTRO ADICIONANDO RANGE DE IDADE
    if(!empty($idadeIni)){
        $this->db->where('u.dt_nascimento BETWEEN "'.$idadeFin.'" AND "'.$idadeIni.'"');
    }
    // FILTRO ADICIONANDO PALAVRAS CHAVE
    if(!empty($palavraChave)){ // AINDA NÃO ESTÁ ATIVO
        //$palavraChave = explode(",", $palavraChave);
        if(empty($funcoes)){
            $this->db->join("funcao_usuario as fu", "fu.id_usuario = u.id_usuario");
        }
        $this->db->join("funcao as f", "f.id_funcao = fu.id_funcao");
        $this->db->join("escolaridade as esc", "esc.id_usuario = u.id_usuario");
        $this->db->join("usuario_idioma as ui", "ui.id_usuario = u.id_usuario");
        $this->db->join("idioma as i", "i.id_idioma = ui.id_idioma");

        $palavraChave = explode(",", $palavraChave);
        $arrayFuncao = [];

        foreach($palavraChave as $palavras){
            array_push($arrayFuncao, "'f.nome' => $palavras");
        }

        var_dump($arrayFuncao);
        die();

        $this->db->or_like($arrayFuncao);

        /*$this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->where_in("f.nome", $palavraChave);
            $this->db->or_group_start();
                $this->db->where_in("esc.curso", $palavraChave);
                $this->db->or_group_start();
                    $this->db->where_in("i.nome", $palavraChave);
                $this->db->group_end();
            $this->db->group_end();
        $this->db->group_end();*/
        // campos a percorrer
        /*if( strpos(file_get_contents("texto.txt"),$_POST['palavra']) !== false) {
        echo "tem";
        }else{
        echo "não tem";
        }*/
    }
    // FILTRO BÁSICO
    $this->db->select("u.id_usuario, u.nome, u.sobrenome, u.dt_nascimento, u.pcd, u.conceito, u.dt_alteracao, u.anexo_curriculo");
    $this->db->from("usuario as u");
    $this->db->where("u.id_tipo_usuario", 3);
    $this->db->like("u.nome", $nome);
    $this->db->like("u.sobrenome", $sobrenome);
    $this->db->like("u.cpf", $cpf);
    $this->db->like("u.genero", $sexo);
    $this->db->like("u.pcd", $pcd);
    $this->db->like("u.cid", $cid);
    $this->db->like("u.conceito", $conceito);
    $this->db->like("u.status_2", $status);
    $this->db->order_by("u.nome", "ASC");

    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Nas pesquisas que realizei, as soluções que encontro sempre inclinam para utilizar um foreach e trazer os resultados encontrados para cada palavra-chave, porém não consigo aplicar isso, pois a filtragem não é somente de palavras-chave.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido, e pode me dar o caminho das pedras para a resolução desse problema?

Desde já agradeço a atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver seu problema sua consulta deve realizar seu SELECT percorrendo as 3 tabelas, **independente de haver filtro ou não** (use o LEFT JOIN caso os parametros não sejam obrigatórios).

Após ter seu select inteiro montado, você apenas verifica se foi enviado o filtro da palavra chave e acrescenta na sua busca.

Não tenho experiência com o codeigniter, mas segue um exemplo básico do que seria:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.reference=table2.reference) LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table1.reference=table3.reference);

if ($filtro){
   $sql .= "AND (table1.nome LIKE '%$filtro%' OR table2.cidade LIKE '%$filtro%')";
}

// execute sql.
```

Esse filtro pode e deve ser resolvido direto no SQL, resolvelo em um foreach só aumentaria o processamento e uso de memória de sua aplicação (Além de aumentar muito seu código).